# ios certificate for code signing confusion

Tags: ios, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I am reading [this article](https://www.objc.io/issues/17-security/inside-code-signing/) which explains code signing in iOS/OSX.

I understand that from **KeyChain Access** ultility I can see my certificate, if unfold my developer certificate, I can see there is a private key:
[image]

The article says:

> ...you will find the certificates you have the private key for. To use
> a certificate for signing, you need the private key...

I understand this.

The article also says:

> To export a certificate from your keychain with the private
> key,Command-Click the certificate and choose ‘Export...

which makes me feel the private key is injected inside the certificate.

But the article then says:

> A certificate is — very broadly speaking — a public key combined with
> a lot of additional information that was itself signed by some
> authority

I get confused, the first quote says the certificate contains a private key, but the above quote says a certificate is a public key combined with other inforation. Where is the private key then???

**Can I understand it like this:**

A certificate is actually a public key which holds/nested with a private key? So, if I export the certificate, I am actually exporting both the public key and private key and other info in the form of X509 certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are exporting the certificate, you are not including the private key (unless you select it as well).
More information: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

The article is correct. The certificate, by itself, does not include the private key. However, in the article you are requested to select the certificate **together** with the private key and export it. When doing that, the private key is included in the `.p12` file you are creating.

Comment: Are you saying the article I am reading is wrong (if you read the 2nd quote in my post)?

Comment: If I want another developer using another MacBook to be able to build my project, I should export certificate to him with or without private key???

Comment: Another developer should be able to create their own developer account and build and run the app using their own account. If you want another developer to be able to code-sign your app to send it to apple and release it (or sign it for enterprise development), they will need to have both the certificate and the private key. You should be careful sharing your private key, especially when it comes to APNS (which is not this case), but if the wrong person would get it you can revoke your certificate at apple and create a new one. Meaning the old one cannot be used anymore.